# Bull separate processes times out with "job stalled more than allowable limit"

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to implement Bull into my TypeScript project. I have the following code:

**index.ts**

```
import Bull, {
    Queue
} from 'bull';

void(async function() {
    const monitorQueue: Bull.Queue < any > = new Bull(`stock`, {
        redis: {
            port: 1234,
            host: 'xxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxx'
        }
    });
    monitorQueue.on('error', err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    monitorQueue.on('failed', async function(job, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    monitorQueue.on('completed', async function(job, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    Promise.all([
        monitorQueue.add({
            foo: 'bar1'
        }),
        monitorQueue.add({
            foo: 'bar2'
        }),
        monitorQueue.add({
            foo: 'bar3'
        }),
        monitorQueue.add({
            foo: 'bar4'
        })
    ]).then(() => {
        monitorQueue.process(4, 'C:/Users/Documents/src/processor.js');
    })
})();
```

**processor.js**

```
module.exports = function(/*job*/) {
    return 42;
};
```

I can see from the console that the new node threads have spawned, but the processor is never run and eventually times out and `monitorQueue.on('error')` is called with the following error: `Error: job stalled more than allowable limit`.

Console logs:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65243/a4d6d909-6ee8-460c-ad20-4be41e364f17
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
(node:3572) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65249/f0e20585-d0a9-4c07-a24e-c1d05d8ce48c
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65250/7a49432d-b39c-43c5-949a-5862ee20255d
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65251/ea8ba70f-823e-4130-9622-0a75b51e8ad9
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65252/3ce00295-f418-46d8-9c9b-68af69a8a027
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
(node:3340) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13784) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19064) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3684) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error: job stalled more than allowable limit
    at C:\Users\Documents\node_modules\bull\lib\queue.js:963:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

I've tested this code in a vanilla JS project and it works fine (the console outputs `42` as expected).